# How to use wmic job get/list in CMD to get process name and location?

Tags: process, location, cmd, jobs, wmic

I need to get the **exact location of a process name** that a scheduled job is executing. I want to use WMIC JOB (if you have any other suggestions.. let me know) to get that, but I don't know HOW exactly. I've tried several variations but no luck so far.

How should I?

Comment: Of course I tried, it's just that WMIC is a huge subject and I don't know what to do with it exactly. :)

Answer (score 15):

The following will work, though you only need "`CommandLine`" *or* "`ExecutablePath`" - not both:

```
wmic process where "ProcessID=1111" get CommandLine, ExecutablePath
```

It will return something like the following, showing where the program for PID 1111 is running:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MyProgram\Agent\agent.exe"
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is something to begin.

Get the process identifier of the service `Schedule`

```
wmic service where name='schedule' get ProcessId
ProcessId
288
```

Get the process which parent process identifier is the `Schedule` service

```
wmic process where ParentProcessId=288
```

---

Edited

I don't think that in Microsoft system jobs are what you are looking for :

A job object allows groups of processes to be managed as a unit. Job objects are namable, securable, shareable objects that control attributes of the processes associated with them. Operations performed on a job object affect all processes associated with the job object. Examples include enforcing limits such as working set size and process priority or terminating all processes associated with a job.

I think you are looking for process.

To answer your question I look for the processes started by the schedule service. If you want the exact location, it's given by the property `ExecutablePath`.

```
wmic process where ParentProcessId=288 get ExecutablePath
ExecutablePath
C:\Windows\system32\wuauclt.exe
```

Comment: The unnecessary comments were removed.
Those commands are related to how to get to Schedule service, not to the location of a process name (+process name). Am I missing somethig? Why did you use WMIC SERVICE / PROCESS and not JOB? Is that part of all of this? Thanks.

Comment: I see. But my point is **not necessary** to look for processes started by the schedule service. For example, if the schedule service is disabled, the code won't find all what I need.

Comment: I've got some code to do what I need, but it's not short as WMIC (JOB or whatever) can be, and that's why I search for alternative(s).

Comment: I thought about something in this direction- `WMIC job "TaskName" get command`. Something like that. Thanks again.

Comment: I modify my answer about Job.

Comment: What does it mean in the buttom line?

Comment: Agreed. But I tried >< long time ago, but I tried alot of variations. I'll try again soon. In the meantime, if you have some ideas- let me know them.

Comment: OK. Problem is not solved, and it can't be unfortunately. You can lock this thread. Thanks for everyone :)

Answer (score -2):

WMIC has a progressive help built-in, so you can learn its syntax using `/?` at any place

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic
wmic:root\cli>/?

[global switches] <command>
```